# how to get five rows before a index point and calculate the mean and store in next row in pandas dataframe with date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data like this
[image]

I need to calculate average of 'Close' price of previous 5 days and store it in a new column'Average_price' for the next row. 
For 1950-01-10, I need to calculate from 1950-01-03 to 1950-01-09 and put in 'Average_price' for 1950-01-10.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: you should to add your code as text, not as image

Comment: Downvoting for sharing a picture rather than using something as simple as: stock_data.head().to_dict() and post that here -1

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
stock_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Open':      [16.66, 16.85, 16.93, 16.98, 17.08] * 2,
    'High':      [16.66, 16.85, 16.93, 16.98, 17.08] * 2,
    'Low':       [16.66, 16.85, 16.93, 16.98, 17.08] * 2,
    'Close':     [16.66, 16.85, 16.93, 16.98, 17.08] * 2,
    'Volume':    [1260000.0, 1890000.0, 2550000.0, 2010000.0, 2520000.0] * 2,
    'Adj Close': [16.66, 16.85, 16.93, 16.98, 17.08] * 2
}, pd.date_range('1950-01-03', periods=10, freq='B'))
```

---

**Solution**
Use a combination of [**`pd.Series.rolling`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and [**`pd.Series.shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
stock_data.assign(
    Average_price=
        stock_data['Adj Close'].rolling(5).mean().shift()
)

            Adj Close  Close   High    Low   Open     Volume  Average_price
1950-01-03      16.66  16.66  16.66  16.66  16.66  1260000.0            NaN
1950-01-04      16.85  16.85  16.85  16.85  16.85  1890000.0            NaN
1950-01-05      16.93  16.93  16.93  16.93  16.93  2550000.0            NaN
1950-01-06      16.98  16.98  16.98  16.98  16.98  2010000.0            NaN
1950-01-09      17.08  17.08  17.08  17.08  17.08  2520000.0            NaN
1950-01-10      16.66  16.66  16.66  16.66  16.66  1260000.0           16.9
1950-01-11      16.85  16.85  16.85  16.85  16.85  1890000.0           16.9
1950-01-12      16.93  16.93  16.93  16.93  16.93  2550000.0           16.9
1950-01-13      16.98  16.98  16.98  16.98  16.98  2010000.0           16.9
1950-01-16      17.08  17.08  17.08  17.08  17.08  2520000.0           16.9
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I couldn't see that. So I commented my answer after I got the way

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer using pd.rolling() method in pandas

```
avg_price=stock_data.rolling(window=5).mean().shift()['Close']
stock_data['Average_Close_5_days']=avg_price
```

The rolling method takes the current row also, so I had to shift the rows by one to store the correct values.

Answer (score -1):

That's a very sophisticated answer by @piRSquared.

I generally use .loc as it is better with indexing and has no trouble with copies

```
stock_data.loc[:, 'Average_price'] = stock_data.loc[:, 'Adj Close'].rolling(window = 5).mean().shift()
```

Comment: The use `pd.DataFrame.assign` is a method for adding a new column to a copy of a dataframe.  Therefore avoiding any copy errors and not overwriting existing dataframes.  Otherwise, this is an identical answer to mine.

Comment: We generally offer each other the courtesy of mentioning minor differences/changes as comments, rather than writing a new answer with the same thing. It's clear as day that this answer was contrived from @piRSquared 's answer. You might choose to move your answer to a comment, or this will be downvoted - the choice is yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not have the reps for putting a comment earlier. Otherwise, I would have. It's really not a big deal. In fact I acknowledged the same. I do not understand how big of an offense it was, as your comment seems to be @COLDSPEED

Comment: You have two options: 1. Wait till you have enough rep to comment. 2. Convert your answer to a community wiki. Otherwise, it seems like you are trying to downplay piR's answer by "offering a simpler alternative" while at the same time piggybacking from any possible votes/rep gain for an answer that was not yours.

Comment: "That's a very sophisticated answer by @piRSquared.

I generally use .loc as it is better with indexing and has no trouble with copies" How is this in any way downplaying piRSquared's answer? Did not know that highly sophisticated coders indulged in petty arguments.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is merely offering you advice on how we generally handle these types of situations.  It really should be taken as just that.  I'm sure neither I nor cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ would want to discourage you from answering questions.  But the heart of what you're offering is the same as mine.  The value you're attempting to add is to suggest that accessing the column `'Adj Close'` is better done via `loc`.  That is a subjective claim that I would argue.  But despite that, it is a minor difference.  It is your choice how to conduct yourself, but we tend to avoid that sort of thing.

Comment: It's also upto you to take a downvote as a personal attack and resort to childish, petty retorts.

Comment: It is hard to beat the "pandas troup" including: Coldspeed, piRSquared, jezrael and Maxu etc in speed. I don't actually know how much but you guys are really helping the pandas community grow showing how quick and simple pandas can be. I'd like sometimes, though, that we could add things to each others answers by editing (like examples and speedtests) rather than this trying to be a competition of some sort. (this is just a general comment).  --- One last thing: These questions should be downvoted for sharing screenshot rather than helping with a small sample.